# C# display a string from a sql database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, listbox

I am trying to make a small contact book that takes contacts details from a mssql database.It has 3 tables: contacts, last_talk(last time i talked with a contact+short description of the discussion), and another table(that has both primary keys from the first 2 tables )

On the form(tab of tabcontrol) where i display the contacts, i have added 2 listboxes, one loads and displays the contacts names, and the second listbox loads the "Last talk" list for every contact i select depending how many "talks" i had with a contact.

Now I am trying to display inside a label.Text and inside a richTextBox.Text from my database, when i select a field in my "Conversation List" listBox.

My database has 3 tables: 1 for contacts, 1 for discussions/talks, 1 for creating a relation between the first 2 tables.

Here is a part of the code:

```
private void PopulateSelectedTalk()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM LastTalk WHERE Id = @ID";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = lstConversationList.SelectedValue;


            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                lblLastTalk.Text = rdr["LastTalkSubject"].ToString();
                rtxtLastTalkDescription.Text = rdr["LastTalkDescription"].ToString();

            }
            rdr.Close();
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
    private void lstConversationList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateSelectedTalk();
    }
```

I had a very similar problem that i posted here: [C# Displaying a sql database object's name in a label.Text property on "SelectedIndexChanged" Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186589/c-sharp-displaying-a-sql-database-objects-name-in-a-label-text-property-on-sel)

And after i added

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = lstConversationList.SelectedValue;
```

it worked.

However, now when i'm trying to use lstConversationList.SelectedValue;  i get the following exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a DataRowView to a Int32.

The exception is thrown by this line: SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

When i hover the mouse over the "Listbox.SelectedValue" in debug mode in the previous issue, i get the value of "1", when i hover over the "Listbox.SelectedValue" in the code i posted above i get "System.DataRowView"

Here is the code from the previous question(it works):

```
private void PopulateContactLabels()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Id = @ID";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = lstContactList.SelectedValue;

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                lblContactName.Text = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                lblCompany.Text = rdr["Company"].ToString();
                lblOccupation.Text = rdr["Occupation"].ToString();
                lblPhoneNumber.Text = rdr["PhoneNumber"].ToString();
                lblEmail.Text = rdr["Email"].ToString();
            }
            rdr.Close();
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
```

What am i missing/doing wrong?
Please help!

Edit: Code that sets the items in lstConversationlist

```
private void PopulateTalkList()
    {
        string query = "SELECT a.LastTalkSubject FROM LastTalk a " + "INNER JOIN ContactLastTalk b ON a.Id = b.LastTalkId " +
            "WHERE b.ContactId = @ContactId";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactId", lstContactList.SelectedValue);
            DataTable lastTalkTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(lastTalkTable);

            lstConversationList.DisplayMember = "LastTalkSubject";
            lstConversationList.ValueMember = "Id";
            lstConversationList.DataSource = lastTalkTable;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code that sets the items in the _lstConversationList_?

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you set the DataSource of the `lstConversationList` to a DataTable and forget to set its `ValueMember` property to the name of the column that contains the value to retrieve from the SelectedValue property.

When you set the DataSource property to a DataTable, each item in the ListBox.Items collection is a DataRowView. If you don't set the `ValueMember` property, then SelectedValue has no way to know from which column read its return value. It just returns the whole DataRowView instance, and, of course, this is not the integer you are searching for.

So when you fill the lstConversationList do not forget to write

```vb
private void PopulateTalkList()
{

    ' NOTE. you need to add also the ID field to the select query

    string query = @"SELECT a.Id, a.LastTalkSubject 
                     FROM LastTalk a INNER JOIN ContactLastTalk b 
                     ON a.Id = b.LastTalkId
                     WHERE b.ContactId = @ContactId";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactId", lstContactList.SelectedValue);
        DataTable lastTalkTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(lastTalkTable);

        lstConversationList.DisplayMember = "LastTalkSubject";
        lstConversationList.ValueMember = "Id";
        lstConversationList.DataSource = lastTalkTable;
     }
}
```

Comment: I am using a DataTable in the method that displays in the "Conversation List" listBox, where i display the conversations i had with the selected contact(in my contact name listBox).

Comment: using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactId", lstContactList.SelectedValue);
                DataTable lastTalkTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(lastTalkTable);

                lstConversationList.DisplayMember = "LastTalkSubject";
                lstConversationList.ValueMember = "Id";
                lstConversationList.DataSource = lastTalkTable;
             }

Comment: Should i share the data tables between the methoids? or should i use another one in my  PopulateSelectedTalk(); method?

Comment: Looking at your edit, you need to add also the ID column to the select query for this ValueMember to work

Answer (score 0):

the Value should be string, so the thing will be

```
lstConversationList.SelectedValue.toString();
```